# ecdsa nonce reuse to compute the private key, modular inverse question

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, dsa, modular-arithmetic

I am following along some cryptography challenges:, in particular ECDSA Nonce Reuse here (second problem):
https://blog.coinbase.com/capture-the-coin-cryptography-category-solutions-fe94d82165c5

I understand all the math, except this part:

```
def modinv(a, modulus): return pow(a, modulus — 2, modulus)
def divmod(a, b, modulus): return (a * modinv(b, modulus)) % modulus
```

Why is it `modulus - 2`? Shouldn't it be `modulus - 1?` I thought the modular inverse of `a mod n` would be $a^{n-1}$? Since $a * a^{n-1} = a^n = 1$?

Is it something to do with the fact that the EC group is size `order`, but the "group in the exponential" is size `order - 1`? I don't really understand though. We need to compute the private key as $\frac{ks'-z}{r}$. But according to ecdsa: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm r and s are all calculated mod n? So why are we doing n - 2? But then confusingly, k is selected in the set [1, .., n-1].

So yeah just a clear cut explanation would be helpful. Thanks.

Thanks for the help!

Oh wait, maybe this is really dumb: we just want the private key, and the private key exists in the integer multiplicative group [1, .., n-1], which is size n-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the modular inverse of $r$

By [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation)

$$a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$$

Then
$$a^{\phi(m)-1} \equiv a^{-1} \pmod{m}$$

Now, for a prime $p$, $\phi(p) = p-1$ then we have

$$a^{p-2} \equiv a^{-1} \pmod{p}$$

---

**Note 1:** The multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ contains $p-1$ elements, the zero is not included.

**Note 2:** Not all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ has multiplicative inverse. To have one, $x \in \{1,\ldots,m-1\}$ we must have $\gcd(m,x)=1$

**Note 3:** The order of Secp256k1 is prime.

Comment: Right, yeah, the private key "lives in" the exponent, which is size n - 1, so that's all we care about.

Comment: @Luke you don't want to include $k=0$ case.